# Express sessions cookies are not being set for client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, frontend, express-session

When I use postman with my API  I can see the cookies being set on the Postman app, so when I need to do any subsquent request, the cookie can be checked to see who the user is, when I try to implement this on the client it does not set cookies.

[image]

I see the same response in the server for both cases

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2019-12-31T19:12:25.238Z,
     originalMaxAge: 720000,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: false,
     sameSite: true } }
```

when I check the frontend for cookies

[image]

and same server response...

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2019-12-31T19:14:11.811Z,
     originalMaxAge: 720000,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: false,
     sameSite: true } }
```

I have setup CORS and just not sure what is the issue, I need to know if the user is logged in , so I can setup navigation and also so I can have a user dashboard .. I need to know who the logged in user is! Please take a look at my github repo , thanks for your time.

github repo to recreate issue: https://github.com/fullstackaccount/express_connection 
 - mongodb local DB runs for server side.

Comment: I don't know exactly  what client code is having this problem (hint, it would be easier to help if you identified exactly what client code has the problem), but you may need the axios option `withCredentials: true` or fetch option `credentials: 'include'` in order to send cookies with the ajax call.

Comment: @jfriend00 has the correct solution, as you can read in your own code, you don't provide the `withCredentials` in your axios request